# enviar de manera correcta parametros via $.get jquery

Tags: jquery

tengo un formulario html que envia datos via $.get hacia un php que procesa todo, pero antes de enviarlo guardo cada valor en una variable para luego armar una cadena y asi enviarselo al php:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nombre">
<input id="apellido">
<select id="cargo"><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>

<button id="procesar">Procesar</button>


<script>
$("#procesar").on("click",function(){
let nombre = $("#nombre").val();
let apellido = $("#apellido").val();
let cargo = $("#cargo").val();

var data_proc = "nombre="+nombre+"&apellido="+apellido+"&cargo="+cargo;
alert(data_proc);
$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "procesar.php",data: data_proc,dataType: "html",
success: function(respuesta){
alert(respuesta);
}

});

});
</script>
```

todo funciona bien hasta que el cliente envia un caracter como `&` dentro de cualquier input, alli me altera todo el sistema ya que el $.get detecta lo que sigue despues de `&` como un parametro en la url.

Notas:

1. este es un codigo para explicar mi pregunta, no es algo real ya que obviamente yo valido las entradas.
2. no quisiera reemplazar el `&` por otro caracter y luego en el php volverlo a reemplazar ya que esto es poco ortodoxo

Mi Pregunta es: ahy una forma de enviar mis `val()` directamente y sin almacenarlas en una variable, no uso el submit porque dentro de mi script tengo condicionales que cambian el valor de las entradas

Comment: Usas GET o POST ? Ya que indicas que usas GET pero en tu código envías la información usando POST

Comment: uso POST aunque no es muy relevante pero de todas maneras es solo un ejemplo de codigo

Comment: Es que, igual que en cualquier lenguaje de programación, cuando envías datos por web hay símbolos y palabras reservadas. El `&` es uno de ellos! Por eso precisamente se utiliza el [*percent encoding*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) para estas cosas. En el enlace de la documentación de mozilla puedes ver con qué caracteres tienes que tener cuidado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar los datos creando un `objeto` en vez de tu concatenar los datos en un `string`. De ésta manera evitas tener que serializar los datos.

```js
$("#procesar").on("click",function(){
    let nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    let apellido = $("#apellido").val();
    let cargo = $("#cargo").val();

    var data_proc = { 
        nombre: nombre, 
        apellido: apellido, 
        cargo: cargo 
    };
  
  $.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "procesar.phpp",
    data: data_proc,
    success: function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta)
    }
    });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nombre">
<input id="apellido">
<select id="cargo"><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>

<button id="procesar">Procesar</button>
```